# Hyperlink to paragraph in an online Sharepoint document

Tags: sharepoint-online, wopi

Is it possible to get a url of a that when opened in browser, directly goes to a paragraph?

Edit: I am aware of the method to jump to a given page. But for my case, need to jump to a specific paragraph. I am generating the url programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is a way to get a URL to open the word document and goes to certain page.

- First, get the URL to see the Word document (Right-click > Share)
- Append the following to the generated URL:`&action=embedview&wdStartOn=#`
- Replace # with the page number you want to jump to.
- Test the new URL and share it.

Reference link: [URL to a particular section/page in a Word Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408839/url-to-a-particular-section-page-in-a-word-document)

The link will be like:

```
https://domain.sharepoint.com/:w:/s/siteName/Ed-OF7hrC2dOuNvm-tVnWzoBwR7g_PnFJtn_1lGaQCxsWg?e=0KdrUm&action=embedview&wdStartOn=2
```

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for a way to jump to a specific paragraph

Comment: @Codervichar Sorry for that. It may be better to ask experts on word to get a link to paragraph for external use.

Answer (score 0):

You can link to a comment in a Sharepoint 365 Word doc (or I can at least). Create a comment by the paragraph you want to link to, then click on the three dots in the comment and select "link to comment".